# PDO fetch vs rowcount

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I’m having a practice in creating a login script in PHP using PDO, but have run into a slight problem. I’ve got it to check if data is in the fields, but unsure of how to check if the username and password combination is correct. This is a snippet of checking the username and password:

```
# if data is valid, check against values held in the database
if ($valid) {
    $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM authors
    WHERE email = :email AND password = :password';
    
    $s = $dbConnection->prepare($sql);
    $s->bindValue(':email', $email);
    $s->bindValue(':password', $password);
    $s->execute();
    
    $row = $s->fetch();
    
    if($row==1){
        echo "ok";
    }else{
        echo "no";
    }
}
```

When I put in any combination for username and password I get the output for false (i.e. echo ‘no’). Could someone give me a hand please?

---

## UPDATE: Snippet modified

I've used password_verify, but I still have the same result:

```
// if data is valid, check against values held in the database
if ($valid) {
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM author
    WHERE email = :email';
    
    $s = $dbConnection->prepare($sql);
    $s->bindValue(':email', $email);
    $s->execute();
    
    $row = $s->fetch();
    var_dump($row);

    if(count($row) > 0 && password_verify($password, $row['password'])){
        echo 'ok';
        exit;
    }else {
        echo 'Username and Password are not found';
    }
}
```

var_dump of incorrect data:

```
bool(false) Username and Password are not found
```

var_dump of correct data:

```
array(4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "3" ["name"]=> string(7) "a@a.com" ["email"]=> string(7) "a@a.com" ["password"]=> string(1) "a" } Username and Password are not found
```

Comment: `var_dump($row)` and have a look at what you've got.

Comment: `array(1) { ["COUNT(*)"]=> string(1) "1" } no` for correct data, and for incorrect data `array(1) { ["COUNT(*)"]=> string(1) "0" } no`

Comment: Please use correct password validation algorithm with php password_verify()
your validation proceess while somewhat sql injection safe, in incorrect
Correct way:
1. get user record by email or handle
2. validate password using password_verify() (check php manual)
only then user is ok

Comment: i've edited the snippet now to use `password_verify`, I still end up with the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it sorted. solution i used was:

```
# if data is valid, check against values held in the database and then action as appropriate
if ($valid) {
    $sql = 'SELECT id, email, password FROM author
    WHERE email = :email AND password = :password';

    $s = $dbConnection->prepare($sql);
    $s->bindValue(':email', $email);
    $s->bindValue(':password', $password);
    $s->execute();

    $data = $s->fetch();
    if($data != NULL){
        $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = TRUE;
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['id'] = $data['id'];
        header('Location:../admin/');
        exit;
    }else{
        unset($_SESSION['loggedIn']);
        unset($_SESSION['email']);
        unset($_SESSION['id']);
        echo 'Incorrect username/password combination';
    }
}
```